# translate from spark function calls to SQL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset with the schema below.

```
root
 |-- acct_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- firm_bnkg_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- tagged: long (nullable = true)
 |-- transactions: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- mo_yr_buckt: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- acct_id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- eff_dt: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- extn_txn_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mntr_txn_am: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr_dr_in: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- txn_desc_tx: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- txn_auth_dt: date (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- txn_auth_ts: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- tagged: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- firm_bnkg_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- txn_pst_sq_nb: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- pst_dt: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prty_ol_prfl_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- prod_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- acct_type_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- acct_state_cd: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to change the current code to a SQL statement. The current code is like this:

```
val result = ds.select(col("*"), explode(col("transactions")).as("txn"))
  .where("IsValidUDF(txn) = TRUE").groupBy("prty_ol_prfl_id")
  .agg(collect_list("txn").as("transactions"))
```

which produces the following schema:

```
root
 |-- acct_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- firm_bnkg_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- tagged: long (nullable = true)
 |-- transactions: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- mo_yr_buckt: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- acct_id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- eff_dt: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- extn_txn_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mntr_txn_am: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr_dr_in: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- txn_desc_tx: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- txn_auth_dt: date (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- txn_auth_ts: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- tagged: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- firm_bnkg_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- txn_pst_sq_nb: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- pst_dt: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prty_ol_prfl_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- prod_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- acct_type_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- acct_state_cd: string (nullable = true)
```

The IsValidUDF just checks the column tagged for certain values.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **translaton of your code to a spark sql statement** is:

```
val new_df = spark.sql("""
    WITH temp AS(
        SELECT *, explode(transactions) AS txn FROM df 
    )
    SELECT first(id) id, collect_list(txn) AS TRANSACTIONS FROM temp WHERE IsValidUDF(txn) = TRUE GROUP BY id 
""")
```

(just replace `first(id)` with `first(.)` with every column you want to have in the resulting dataframe.

Beforehand make sur that your **udf is registered**:

```
spark.udf.register("IsValidUDF", is_valid_udf)
```

Here is the complete code **with a toy example**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Toy example
val df = Seq((0, List(66,1) ),(1, List(98, 2)),(2, List(90))).toDF("id", "transactions")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
val is_valid_udf = udf((r: Int) => r > 50)

// register udf
spark.udf.register("IsValidUDF", is_valid_udf)
// query
val new_df = spark.sql("""
    WITH temp AS(
        SELECT *, explode(transactions) AS txn FROM df 
    )
    SELECT first(id) id, collect_list(txn) AS TRANSACTIONS FROM temp WHERE IsValidUDF(txn) = TRUE GROUP BY id 
""")
```

**Output:**

```
+---+------------+
| id|TRANSACTIONS|
+---+------------+
|  1|        [98]|
|  2|        [90]|
|  0|        [66]|
+---+------------+
```

which is the original dataframe with transactions > 50 removed.

Comment: Thanks it worked. If you would elaborate more about the uses of first function. Do you have to use it to pull the columns of the aggregate? What happens if I just use the column name? What happens when that column is null?

Comment: The thing is that the explode function has duplicated your rows by the number of elements in each transactions array. After that the collect_list do the reverse operation. But to get back as well the original column you need an aggregated operation but as they were duplicated you can take first(), last(), mean(), or whatever you will get the same value. If a column is null you will also get null. But if you don't put an aggregated operation (for example just using the column name) the code will just throw an error.